# Loading MVC Dropdowns using viewbags ajax when changing a dropdown?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, dropdown, viewbag

```
@Html.DropDownList("CountryID", (SelectList)ViewBag.CounrtyList,new { style = "width:150px;" })

@Html.DropDownList("CityID", (SelectList)ViewBag.CityList,new { style = "width:150px;" })

@Html.DropDownList("StateID", (SelectList)ViewBag.StateList,new { style = "width:150px;" })

@Html.DropDownList("DistrictID", (SelectList)ViewBag.DistrictList,new { style = "width:150px;" })
```

How can I change city, state and district values in a single ajax call when changing the Country dropdown?

Comment: Suggest you study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is called Cascading Drop Downs, and you can see this technique here: [Cascading update of two @Html.DropDownListFor in MVC4 with model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880585/cascading-update-of-two-html-dropdownlistfor-in-mvc4-with-model-binding?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

It links to an example using a partial view, but JSON could be returned instead.  I think that is the best option because you can return a JSON object of:

```
{ cities: [], states: [], districts: [] }
```

And then wire up the cities to the correct DDL.  OR use the partial view approach as linked above but call it 3 times (less efficient that way).